# Control external IP address range for nodes in kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to provide a whitelisted range for connections to a MongoDB Atlas instance running on Google Cloud. VPC Peering isn't yet available on Atlas for Google Cloud - Is it possible to provide a CIDR range for external IP addresses allocated to nodes in a kubernetes cluster?

Alternatively, any tips on ensuring the source of connections are from an authorized node? (Other than SSL + username and password)

Comment: I realize this is an old question. But to people searching, it may be helpful to use the approach of creating a Google Cloud NAT to do this: https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example#step_6_create_a_nat_configuration_using
https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/using-nat#create_nat (using the 'Specify IP addresses for NAT' approach allows creating a fixed IP that may be whitelisted on Atlas)

Comment: While providing links is useful, it would be _more_ helpful to the asker if you posted a summary of the steps involved on the link you posted as external links can go dead / be removed at any time. For more tips, see [answer].

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers to prevent link rot. Instead, add the most relevant information from the link to your answer or alternatively, post the link as a comment instead of an answer. See [this](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) help center article for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to determine which external IPs will be used by VMs (unless you have already [reserved IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)) or clusters. Nevertheless there are some workarounds you could consider.

One of them is making outgoing connections from the POD [via a proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/835425/kubernetes-external-connection-through-single-ip). The proxy could be an [another Pod](https://github.com/johnlabarge/gke-nat-example/blob/master/gke-with-nat-route.jinja) or a [dedicated VM](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#natgateway).
Some other approaches are described on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133755/static-outgoing-ip-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Ok, makes sense, in order to not create a single point of failure we'd need to some non-trivial work. Also, increases server spend. Guess I'd have to ask MongoDB Atlas what timelines they have for supporting VPC peering on Google cloud. Thanks for the answer - I'll see what else I can find out and mark yours as the answer if things work out.